# Netlink sockets

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, netlink

I am trying send a list/array of struct to kernel space from userspace. Similar to [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261440/storing-struct-array-in-kernel-space-linux/)
As recommended there, I am thinking of using sockets for which i found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299386/how-to-use-netlink-socket-to-communicate-with-a-kernel-module). Message is set hello in this line

```
strcpy(NLMSG_DATA(nlh), "Hello");
```

I tried

```
NLMSG_DATA(nlh) = my_list
```

That gave me error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment.

How can I change this to send an array/list using netlinks? If it can't be send this way, how else easily can I do this?

**Update**

My structure

```
typedef struct {
 int val1;
 int val2;
} mystruct;
```

I need to allocate an array/list of these in kernel memory so other system calls can access that list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698396/linux-kernel-copy-from-user-struct-with-pointers

Answer (score 0):

`NLMSG_DATA()` evaluates to a pointer rvalue, so you need to use a copying function like `memcpy(NLMSG_DATA(nlh), my_list, sizeof my_list)`.

The exact details will depend on your data structure.  Presumably you will want to send the number of list entries, then each entry separately.

Comment: So, I build the list, and send the pointer value to kernel. By doing so, can't I access the list in kernel space by just my_userspace_list->next?

Comment: @Alkesh: No.  All accesses to user memory in kernel space use `copy_from_user` or similar, and each must be checked for safety.  Don't make the kernel chase a linked list through user memory.

Comment: @Alkesh: No, userspace pointers should not be directly dereferenced from kernel space.  The correct method is to use `copy_from_user()` and related functions - but it is likely that your list should be serialised into an array for transport between user and kernel space.

Comment: @ephemient/@caf - so memcpy fixed the issue. Now, since I only have the address, how would I use copy_from_user() as I didnt pass the size? I tried the this: copy_from_user(list_in_kernel, (mystruct \*)nlmsg_data(nlh), sizeof((mystruct\*)nlmsg_data(nlh))); That didn't work.

Comment: @Alkesh: You should probably just be directly sending an array of `mystruct` s in the netlink message - then you would just need to allocate a block of kernel memory with `kmalloc()` and do a `memcpy()` on the kernel side.

Comment: @caf- How can I send an array using netlink? I cant find any examples of sending an array directly?

Comment: can you pass `my_list` instead of `&my_list`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send pointer-based structures using netlink sockets. See the [packet structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink#Packet_structure) of netlink: all data must be in a single block.

Comment: Well, if he wanted the pointer values, it would be sufficient ;-)